# Laravel Error : Function name must be a string

Tags: mysql, laravel, smtp, local-storage

```
$files = $request->file('attachment');
$attachmentDataPush = NULL;
if ($request->hasfile('attachment')) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $message->attach($file->getRealPath(), [
            'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'mime' => $file->getMimeType()
             ]);
$filename = 'AttachmentsBox/' . $message->getId() . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::put($filename, $file->get());  
$attachmentDataPush = $attachmentDataPush . "<" . $file()->getClientOriginalName() . ">";
                }
            }
```

I want to add the code I wrote in $ attachmentDataPush side by side in <> but it gives an error. "Function name must be a string" What do you think may be the problem. ?

```
$attachmentDataPush = $attachmentDataPush . "<" . $file()->getClientOriginalName() . ">";
```

Line gives an error.I will insert the transaction into the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attachmentDataPush = $attachmentDataPush . "<" . $file->getClientOriginalName() . ">";
```

I functioned as file (). I accidentally put brackets. The top one is correct.